# Changing className after insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, insertadjacenthtml

I am trying to change my className after the `insertAdjacentHTML()` function. I am using an AJAX request for this and the route `/reviewcombine` is from my backend JavaScript codes.

My codes:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>
        .checked {
            color: orange;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function getTestByID() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //The "/reviewcombine" here is the route from my backend JavaScript
            request.open("GET", "/reviewcombine", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.onload = function () {
                var tests = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var exampleID = 1
                var totalTests = tests.length;

                var testlistings = document.getElementById("testListings");

                for (var testCount = 0; testCount < totalTests; testCount++) {

                    if (tests[testCount].reviewResId == exampleID) {

                        var username = tests[testCount].username;
                        var rating = tests[testCount].rating;

                        var testItem = '<div class="eachtest">\
                                    <h5 style="padding:6px; background-color: #E1ECF4; display: inline-block">@'+ username + '</h5>\
                                    <div style="margin-top: 1px; padding-left: 3px;">\
                                        <p style="color: rgb(255, 136, 0); font-size: 16px; display: inline;">'+ rating + '</p>&nbsp;\
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" id="test_1"></span>\
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" id="test_2"></span>\
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" id="test_3"></span>\
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" id="test_4"></span>\
                                        <span class="fa fa-star" id="test_5"></span>\
                                        &nbsp;\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>';

                        // insertAdjacentHTML() to insert the HTML codes.                  
                        testlistings.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', testItem);

                        //cant change after insertAdjacentHTML????????????????????
                        var star = tests[testCount].rating

                        if (star == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (star == 1) {
                            document.getElementById('test_1').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                        }
                        else if (star == 2) {
                            document.getElementById('test_1').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_2').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                        }
                        else if (star == 3) {
                            document.getElementById('test_1').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_2').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_3').className = "fa fa-star checked"

                        }
                        else if (star == 4) {
                            document.getElementById('test_1').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_2').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_3').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_4').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById('test_1').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_2').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_3').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_4').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                            document.getElementById('test_5').className = "fa fa-star checked"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            request.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="getTestByID()">
    <div id="testListings"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here, I am trying to change my stars to orange and display it based on the `ratings` value.

However, doing this after the `insertAdjacentHTML` function just changes the classNames permanently. The subsequent loops are using the `fa fa-star checked` class instead of the `fa fa-star` class that they should be using. (Doing it before the `insertAdjacentHTML` function is also not possible)

This is an example  of the output I am getting:

[image]

Can someone please help me to identify what is the error here? Any relevant sources would also be a big help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fixed it! Instead of assigning the className in my `if-else` I call the `var testItem` in it and do the `insertAdjacentHTML` after the `if-else` ends.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you are assigning a hard-coded id:

```
<span class="fa fa-star" id="test_1"></span>
```

`document.getElementById('test_1")` is only going to return the first instance of it, because id is supposed to be unique. Try making the id dynamically.